# WSO2 Identity Server (IS-KM) - 5.10.0 - Unable to send "askPassword" email when Event listeners are enabled

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When I enable the below properties in deployment.toml, the SCIM API for Add user with "askPassword" feature is not sending emails.

```
[event.default_listener.identity_mgt]
priority= "50"
enable = false
[event.default_listener.governance_identity_mgt]
priority= "95"
enable = true
[event.default_listener.governance_identity_store]
priority= "97"
enable = true

[identity_mgt.user_onboarding]
ask_password_from_user= true
```

The askPassword email is being sent when I comment out event listeners.

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Have you enabled global notification handling in resident IDP configurations as mentioned in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/creating-users-using-the-ask-password-option/ ?

Comment: @DinaliDabarera - Yes. I have made the changes. Also, when I comment the 50, 95, and 97 listeners, it works.

Comment: @DinaliDabarera - Should I change any other configurations?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue with the same configurations you have mentioned. The ask password email is being sent when the user creation is done via SCIM API and management console too.

Comment: Where have you configured the `smtp` details? Are you seeing any errors upon executing the flow?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna - Thanks for the response, I'm getting emails now. Seems the SMTP server was down the other day,

Comment: @NipunThathsara - Thanks for the response, I configured the output adapter configuration in deployment.toml.